# SMTPClient.Send "Transaction failed: rejected for policy reasons"

Tags: email, powershell, outlook, smtpclient

I've been playing around with Outlook in Powershell using outlook-Redemption library.

What I want to do: I want to be able to automatically send a confirmation mail to an address ( for now statically, later perhaps dynamically appointed).

The problem is that My mail is being rejected by the server and I was hoping if you guys could help me out as to finding out why it's doing this and how/what I should do to send a mail successfully.

For privacy reasons I've changed some names, but it's certainly safe to presume that the ones I use for this script are legit and recognized by the server and not flagged as spam.

### My Code:

```
$mailSMTPServer = "smtp.<server>.com"
$cred = Get-Credential
$mailSMTPUser = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().username
$mailSMTPPass = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().password

$Message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$Message.From = $routlook.CurrentUser.Name + "<"+ $routlook.CurrentUser.SMTPAddress+ ">"
$Message.To.Add("recipient@hotmail.com")
$Message.Subject = "Confirmation"
$Message.IsBodyHtml = $true
$Message.Body = "Thank you for the mail. I'm confirming I have recieved it"
$Message.Sender = $routlook.CurrentUser.SMTPAddress

$SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient( $mailSMTPServer)
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($mailSMTPUser, $mailSMTPPass)

$SMTPClient.Send($Message)
```

### The Error (partially blurred for privacy reasons):

[image]

Comment: Try adding `$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true`.

Comment: Tried that, responded with : `Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Server does not support secure connections."`

Comment: @TomKustermans It means that `smtp.server.com` won't allow you to send emails using that From address. Contact the mail server admin

Comment: That's not the problem, cause It's a valid address for the server. I use the same address in the outlook App and can successfully send mails. Should be something else then?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I'm having the same issue. Tried from multiple clients, on some it works fine on others I get this error message. Can't figure out the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work, if you use  `$Message.From = $routlook.CurrentUser.SMTPAddress`  instead of `$Message.From = $routlook.CurrentUser.Name + "<"+ $routlook.CurrentUser.SMTPAddress+ ">"` ?

Comment: Can you normally send that email through Outlook? Are there any policies on the Server, preventing you to send to external recipients?

Comment: Yes I can send them fine, no problem.

Comment: When you type in your mailadress manually (not using a var) into $Message.From .. does that work ?

Comment: Still thinking, this is a server side thing. What Server is used? Did you worked on that with your (mail)Server Admin?

Comment: I have no knowledge of the mailserver. But I do know that My mailitem's Type is different than other legit mails. Could it be possible that I should try sending SafeMailItems ?

Comment: Get in contact with your mailadmin and explain to him, what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to be sure I do everything I can before contacting the admin. I want to try and send SafeMailItems but I'm not sure how to create them, could you perhaps refer me a source?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104427/discussion-between-tom-kustermans-and-martin).